Calculate combined confidence interval of two variables in a negative binomial model (in R)
I have a multivariable negative binomial model in R for which I want to combine two variables:

Variable 1: binary variable (no/yes)

Variable 2: continuous variable (0-3)


I want to calculate confidence intervals for the combinations of:

Variable 1 + Variable 2

Variable 1 + 2*Variable 2

Variable 1 + 3*Variable 2


I don't want to recode my variables into 1 variable, because I also want to keep the overall estimate for "yes" for Variable 1.
I've read somewhere that the variance for the first combination can be calculated as variance(Variable 1) + variance(Variable 2) + 2*covariance(Variable 1, Variable 2). Does anyone know whether this is correct and how to obtain the variances (and confidence intervals) for the other combinations? Or is there perhaps another way to calculate the combined confidence intervals?

Which package::function did you use to calculate the negative binomial model?

I actually used the mgcv::gam(), since I also have a spline in the model

I feel like this question needs a lot more clarity now...you seem to have omitted not only that there is a GAM, but that 1) there is nonlinearity present and 2) there are additional terms. It would be very helpful to include the full model in order to get a full response to your query, as I was under very different assumptions about what you were testing here.

Your formula for adding variances is correct. But the result may not make much sense. A binary variable can be coded as anything: 0 and 1 or -1 and 1 or 1 and 2019 or whatever. And each choice will give a different variance.
The variance of a proportion does make sense, and that may be what you want, although even using the proportion, it's hard to make sense of the result.
If you tell us why you want to combine these, then maybe someone can suggest a method. What are you going to do once you've combined them?

Thank you for your reply! I want to look at the effect of a certain intervention (yes/no intervention) and I want to see whether this effect decreases over time (1/2/3 years after intervention). However, I also want to keep the overall 'yes treatment' effect. I have tried to combine var1 and var2, but this became too complex for the model (the above representation of the model is a simplified one).

Reading your comments in Peter's answer, it appears you are just interested in the interaction between time in years and treatment. It seems pretty straightforward that this can just be entered as an interaction in the model, whereafter you can easily get the confidence intervals. As Peter already noted, doing what you suggested doesn't really make a ton of sense, and the interaction would establish the treatment differences over time directly anyway. As an example in R:
#### Load Data ####
library(COUNT)
data(rwm5yr)
head(rwm5yr)

#### Fit NB Model ####
nb <- glm.nb(
  docvis ~ outwork * year, 
  data=rwm5yr
)

#### Profile Likelihood CIs ####
confint(nb)

The CIs are directly obtainable:
                    2.5 %        97.5 %
(Intercept)  -55.25742279  21.630737264
outwork       20.10052436 148.751004504
year          -0.01039736   0.028316034
outwork:year  -0.07467642  -0.009898657

This is of course how you would want to model it if you were treating it as strictly continuous (just wanting the overall association of time and the response) rather than knowing what each year's individual associations are (or their conditional means for that matter).
